# Python 3 и командная строка

Tags: python

Нужно использовать командную строку из скрипта Python 3 и получать ответ. Какая для этого есть функция\либа?

Comment: А поподробнее описать проблему можно? Или требуется помощь психолога-телепата?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам нужени модуль [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

```
result = subprocess.check_output(["command", "parameters"]);
```

Comment: не совсем понял, что я должен указывать в параметрах. вот мне нужно выполнить команду 'C:\python32\python Z:\home\192.168.0.15\www\start.pyw start=1 module=server > Z:\home\192.168.0.15\www\test.html'. Как мне правильно воспользоваться этой функцией?

Comment: Не совсем понял, чего вы хотите добиться. Вам нужно из командной строки вызвать питоновский скрипт и его вывод направить в файл или из питоновского скрипта вызвать команду в консоли и получить её вывод?

Comment: Получить ее вывод для разбора. В файл я написал просто чтобы отследить, срабатывает ли команда вообще.

Comment: Тогда `C:\python32\python` - это команда, а `Z:\home\192.168.0.15\www\start.pyw start=1 module=server` - это параметры.

Answer (score 1):

Если просто нужно что-то запустить с помощью консоли, то можно воспользоватся модулем os.

```
os.system('start "" "E:\...\namefolder")
```

Если нужно получить результат работы запускаемой программы, тогда используйте модуль subprocess.

```
from subprocess  import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen('start %s ' % (programm), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out,err = process.communicte()
if out:
   output = out.decode('cp866')
   print(output)
```