# Как в python перехватить вывод из потока std::cout c++ и записать этот вывод в переменную

Tags: python, c++

```
c++

std::cout << "something"

python

output = ...
```

Comment: Как вы запускаете c++? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4760517/7485582

Comment: Через python запускаю экзешник  плюсового проекта

Comment: Ну вот по ссылке есть решение.

Comment: другой [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/187912/178576). ну и [вообще](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bpython%5d%20subprocess%20is%3aa)